# Will a task ever be interrupted by garbage collection if there are no references to it?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

Sanity-check here. Suppose I start a task but I don't await it and I don't store a reference to it. In other words, I just run:

```
async Task PerformLongOperation() {
    await Task.Delay(10 * 1000);
    Debug.WriteLine("All done!");
}

void DoSomething() {
    // Kick off the operation and allow it to complete when it does.
    PerformLongOperation();
}
```

Clearly, without keeping a reference to the `Task` returned by `PerformLongOperation()`, I have no way of knowing if and when it completes. But suppose that that's not necessary in certain instances.

Is there any danger of garbage collection noticing the task running with no references to it, and cancelling it and cleaning it up?

Comment: The Task class has no such bug.  You cannot assume it always completes because you can't ensure it did not die on an unhandled exception.  Or that you kept your program running long enough to allow it to complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  The `Task` class keeps a private static collection with a reference to all currently running tasks, so even if none of your code is holding a reference to it, that will be.  Additionally, tasks all hold onto references of tasks representing their continuations, so any tasks representing continuations (through any number of layers of indirection) from a running task cannot be collected either.

Comment: What about child tasks (attached and not attached to parent)?

Comment: @JohnyL That's a continuation, which I mentioned in the answer.  A task needs to have a reference to all of its continuations, so that it can tell them to run when it has completed.

Comment: Beg your pardon, am I right that continuation task and child task are the same thing?

Comment: @JohnyL If you aren't referring to continuations then you're going to need to be more specific about what you are referring to.